# Debian wifi not working

Tags: debian, wifi

I recently dual-booted Debian stretch with Windows. Everything is working correctly but I can't connect to wifi. After some search I installed realtek-firmware and firmware-iwlwifi as suggested by similar queries. But I still can't connect to my wifi. My ethernet connection works well though. This is my lspci output

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

Can you please suggest a fix? Thank you in advance :)

UPDATE:
dmesg output:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   13.568649] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode (-2)
[   13.568650] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) page? The error you get means "module not found".

Comment: The wireless card in question is Intel, corresponding to "03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)", correct? If so, what does `lsmod | grep iwlwifi` return?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I think [this](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) should work. I'm sorry at the moment I don't have a debian version up and running to test this.

[iwlwifi](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi)

Comment: I already did that but it failes to load firmware. Dmesg output is in update